# The using of has and have in question

Tags: grammar

Iam asking about the verb have when using it as possessing matter.
I know the verb (has) comes with he,she,it and the verb (have) comes with I, you, we, they.

1. Now,why we say; he has a car, and we say in the question, does he have a car?

My question why not say, does he has a car?

2. Also, which sentence  is correct?

> Does he has the responsibility of the accident.
>   Does he have the responsibility of the accident

Comment: There are Lots of duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you put a form of *do*, *have*, or *be* in front of a verb, then *do*, *have* or *be* changes according to subject and not the word after it.

> Now,why we say; he has a car, and we say in the question, does he have a car?

In the question, the verb *does* changes according to subject instead of *have*.

Note that you can say do + *verb* without asking a question; this is a form of emphasis.  So you can see the difference easily:

> He likes candy.
>
> He does like candy.
>
> They like candy.
>
> They do like candy.

If *have* is the second word it follows the same logic.

> He has two pieces of candy.
>
> He does have two pieces of candy.
>
> Does he have two pieces of candy?
>
> Do I have two pieces of candy?